# How to re-enable console login on Raspbery Pi image?

Tags: boot, terminal

I have an image, which boots into neither console, nor GUI (only web services available). How this could be done? How to re-enable console login?

I can only edit image, not run `raspi-config`

Comment: It sounds like you are running something other than standard Raspberry OS. If you hope to get answers you should explain further. what you have.

Comment: I have an image. I can boot it. I can't login to it. Where to look?

Comment: is SSH enabled? Have you tried one of the virtual terminals? Do you get a command prompt?

Comment: No, `ssh` is also disabled. No virtual terminals. No command prompt. This is the question: need to get one. How this could be broken?

Comment: @SteveRobillard do you know, where `raspi-config` writes it's boot mode Console/GUI?

Comment: Why not enable ssh?  Every boot by raspberry pioS looks for the ssh / ssh.txt file and enables it if present.  Source for raspi-config is on github https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config but you will need to be able to access the ext4 partition of the SD card to replicate its changes.

Comment: No idea how you got yourself into this position, but I would advise burning a fresh image and starting again.

Comment: if you can edit the image, then take a look at what raspi-config does to enable console login vs gui - and perform those tasks on the image